# how do i achieve timezone independence in highcharts export server?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have highcharts export server(2.0.14) configured in Europe timezone and i have my system in indian time zone. i am using java to create a json and sent it to the highcharts export server to get an png image of the graph.
But the export server is generating an x-axis(datetime) which is timezone dependent.
how do i achieve timezone independence for x-axis

i have tried using

```
time:{
   useUTC: false
}
```

following is the fiddle link.

https://jsfiddle.net/btcLqhs0/

if you sent the same json in the fiddle to the highcharts export server the x-axis scale would be different.

The image attached is the result of the highcharts export server .

I expect the x-axis of the graph from highcharts export server  and highcharts server to match[image]

Comment: Highcharts export server uses UTC and it can't be disabled from the regular chart options.
Please get familiar with this topic, it should help you: https://www.highcharts.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=40349

Comment: @SebastianWędzel thanks for the reply. 
If i set **useUTC : true** , i get my x-axis scale in GMT and
if i set **useUTC : true , timezoneoffset: some _val**
This some_val should be user timezone specific . i want to set the date that is passed as it is on the scale.

Comment: Actually, you are right, you should be able to rectify this time differences by using timezoneoffset. I created a simple demo -  https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/4p0aqb2r/ and tested it on the: https://export.highcharts.com/ and it works, timezone has changed.

Comment: @SebastianWędzel thanks for the example. 

Highcharts export server supports timezoneoffset from 2.0.9 onwards . But the problem i was facing was if i open a graph through the browser (which calls highcharts.com) it detects the timezone of the client and renders the graph scale according to client timezone. 
But for a graph to generated by just the backend (hits the highchart_export_server) i had to sent some timezoneoffset information along  with  "useUTC":true so that the graph is adjusted according to the timezone i want.

Comment: @SebastianWędzel is there a way i can set exact date i get (2019 / 11 / 06 12:31:40), on the x-axis without setting the timezoneoffset in highcharts export server ?

Comment: I am afraid that it is impossible because highcharts export server changes date time to UTC format and you need to set timezoneoffset to rectify time to your local timezone.

Comment: @SebastianWędzel Thanks will do as you suggested.
useUTC : true , timezoneoffset: some _val
some_val is the required timezone Offset